# show mysql record in string sorted order

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table with records are

**product_title**

2 PRI + 8 Port FXS PSTN Simulator Adv
2 PRI + 8 Port FXS PSTN Simulator
2 PRI + 4 Port FXS PSTN Simulator Adv
2 PRI + 4 Port FXS PSTN Simulator
2 PRI + 32 Port FXS PSTN Simulator Adv
2 PRI + 32 Port FXS PSTN Simulator

Now i want to use mysql query to get result of these records in following sequence

2 PRI + 4 Port FXS PSTN Simulator
2 PRI + 4 Port FXS PSTN Simulator Adv
2 PRI + 8 Port FXS PSTN Simulator
2 PRI + 8 Port FXS PSTN Simulator Adv
2 PRI + 32 Port FXS PSTN Simulator
2 PRI + 32 Port FXS PSTN Simulator Adv

I have tested cast, convert, order by (product_title + 0) etc. But my desire result will not come. Can anybody helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the 'Adv' at the end of the title, but I think this should work;

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY product_title ASC`

Comment: can you run this this?

Comment: Can you post your current SQL query first?

Comment: it comes 32 original, 32 adv, 4 original, 4 adv, 8 original, 8 adv

Comment: Ah stupid me, it's because 3 is lower than 4, the 32 is coming up first. It does not work for numbers very well. I'm no SQL expert but if you don't have many results you can try to order them with PHP.

Comment: Maybe here you can find a solution; [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51602/How-to-Sort-Alphanumeric-Data-in-SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order by a substring?

```
... ORDER BY SUBSTRING(product_title, 0, 4), SUBSTRING(product_title, 8, 14)
```

(You may have to adjust the indices and maybe add another constraint for the whole product_title, can't test right now)

Answer (score 0):

Any ordering you do will not work as you expect as you are dealing with strings so `34` will come before `4` however you **could** do this:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
ORDER BY 
convert(SUBSTRING(product_title, 9, 2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

This converts the `4`, `8`, `32` into an integer and then orders by it **HOWEVER** this is messy and relies on your data being in this format.

If your data varies, I would look at doing this via PHP instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a3d/10/0)

Note: You can also tweak this to order by the first number in your data as well.